# Perl giving output and the same an input for Windows command prompt in Windows

Tags: perl, batch-file

I am creating a simple Perl script returning the output 1 or 0. Then we need to get the output value in the Windows batch file as an input.

How to get the output as an input in a batch file?

Sample batch file - Test.bat:

```
 perl -w Test.pl & rem returning 1 or 0 might be 

 rem if the output is 1 then 
 rem (  we do something )
 rem else 
 rem ( goto BatchEnd )
```

Comment: If you're just looking for the batch equivalent of `$?`, it's `%ERRORLEVEL%`. Or is the perl script actually printing an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to all.

```
for /f %%i in ('perl -w a.pl') do set VAR=%%i
if %VAR% EQU 1 ( goto BatchEnd )
echo hi
pause
:BatchEnd
```

I have got the answer.